# keep getting undefined property name

Tags: properties, names

I have an object created with

```
function makeMyObject(eventName, idzName, classzName){
    function eDetails(eventName, idzName, classzName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
        this.idzName = idzName;
        this.classzName = classzName;
      }

let cObj = new eDetails(eventName, idzName, classzName);
console.log(cObject) 
return cObj;}
}
```

► eventDetails {eventName: "event1", idzName: "A", classzName: "L1"}
this is correct,

when it return to the calling function and I ..

```
let cObjct = makeMyObject(eventName, idzName, classzName);
console.log(cObjct);
```

► eventDetails {eventName: "event1", idzName: "A", classzName: "L1"}
this is also correct,

now I want to push that object to the array.

```
Function makeEventList(orgObjct) {
    let evntList = [];
      evntList.push(orgObject);
      console.log(evntList);
      return evntList;
  }

let myArray = makeEventList(orgObjct;
console.log(myArray);
```

► eventDetails
eventDetails {eventName: "event1", idzName: "A", classzName: "L1"}
length:1
**proto**:Array(0)

however, now I wish to place 1 of those into a variable.

```
function myFunction (myArray, cObjct){
let x = cObjct.idzName
console.log(x);
return x;}
```

► undefined

I've also tried,

```
function myFunction (cObjct){
let x = $(cObjct).prop(idzName);
console.log(x);}
```

► A >> This is only partially CORRECT. A is the idzName. if $.prop() get the first property name fo cObject, it should be 'event1', further where's the 3rd property name? how do I access that?

I've also tried

```
function myFunction (cObjct, idzName) 
let x = $(cObjct).prop(idzName);
    console.log(x);
return x;}
```

same result -> ► A >> This is only partially CORRECT. A is the idzName. if $.prop() get the first property name fo cObject, it should be 'event1', further where's the 3rd property name? how do I access that?

i've also tried doing 2 function 1 like first another like this

```
function myFunction (cObjct, idzName) 
    let x = $(cObjct).prop(idzName);
        console.log(x);
    return x;}
```

► undefined

So how do I correctly get the value of a specified property name from an array object?

thanks

Comment: I didn't specifically pass the property names to function, because my understanding is that they were apart of the object already. Is this understanding incorrect?

Comment: if I'm going to compare 2 items, 1 in the array and 1 OUT of the array object to object by means of property name. Then don't I need to extract out, myArray.Object.property.name = idzName(example). So that I can compare with an object that's NOT in the array, which i used let o = myObj2["idzName"] which does return an A not in an array, I am assuming ["A'] and A are not equal.